# Interaction vacuum and free vacuum states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, scattering, vacuum, s-matrix-theory

Why we prepare in and out states from interacting vacuum rather than free vacuum even if the total Hamiltonian is just free Hamiltonian at times far past and far future? What is really the difference between the two vacuum types physically? Why we use interaction picture in scattering experiment?

Comment: It would help, if you gave some reference to what topic you are struggling with. Different textbooks have different approaches, and it is difficult to answer your question without knowing your starting point.

Comment: I am struggling with S-Matrix in quantum field theory.

Comment: By "reference" I mean reference to a book and a chapter. Which book and which chapter are you learning the topic from? Or, if you learning the topic from a video, can you give a reference to it?